# How to disable HTML background color reflecting in Safari iOS menu and address bar?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

In a mobile browser you can refresh the page when you are at the beginning of the page and then drag the page down. This will then fill up the gap between the address bar of the browser and the page itself with the background color set for the `<html>` tag (and also show a busy icon in that gap).

If you don't set a background color for `<html>` then the background color of this gap is not managed by the website. Now this behavior works fine for most mobile browsers (at least the ones I have tested).

But in Safari iOS, the background color shines through the menu and address bar when the page is at the top:

[image: Safari iOS]

The CSS code looks like that:

```css
html {
  background: #b93cff;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
}
```

I have tried to tinker with a meta tag just to see if I can change the current behavior:

```html
<meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#4285f4">
```

But this has no effect at all.

Can anybody tell how to address Safari iOS color theming to behave normal instead of picking up my html background color for its styling?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? To my knowledge iOS 15+ uses `<meta name="theme-color" ...` [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/)

Comment: Hi Harrison, I am on iOS 16.6.1. But regardless of the support of `theme-color`, I'm looking for a way to prevent Safari styling itself using my background color. Or maybe its not applying a style but rather some kind of transparency of the browser menu- and address bar?

Comment: Ah I see, I think it does that and there's no way to stop it but you can set "Reduce Transparency" in the Accessibility Settings, but I don't think it will solve the issue fully

Comment: Well ok, so changing the settings locally unfortunately doesn't affect the clients browsers as well^^. Pitty, but if that's the way Safari behaves and there's no way to change it, then it shall be. Many thanks for having a look.